# View(Template) does not update when the controller changes

Tags: angularjs, templates, updates, directive

I have a directive that pushes element to an array, and then shows the elements on the view, the problem is that even though the array gets updated (the log shows the correct values) the view keeps showing the empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I do not need the parent's $scope for anything, all I'm adding/modifying is on the directive's scope.

Directive:

```
app.directive('streaming', function(){
    return  {
        restrict: 'EA', 
        scope: {
            live: '&',
            data: '&',
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.messages=[];
        //.....
        //Eventually this reaches $scope.messages.push({..});
        },
        templateUrl: '/directives/templates/streaming.html'
        }});
```

Template:

```
<div class="row" >
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640px" height="360px"></canvas>
</div>
<div ng-show="live" id="chat">
    {{messages}}
    <div ng-repeat="m in messages">
        <div ng-if="m.type==0"><!--sistema-->
            {{m.val}}
        </div>
        <div ng-if="m.type==1"><!--Usuario-->
            {{m.val}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we see how the directive is called on the main HTML document ?

Comment: it's just <div streaming live=1>

Comment: it's more important than that. you may be blocked by isolated scopes or the misused of a some angular directives. How do you add messages to your array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to wrap the `$scope.messages` modifications in a `$scope.apply()` to get the view to reflect the actual value. I'm not entirely sure why. This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your directive like this:

```
app.directive('streaming', function() {
    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        function init() {
            // Copy any stuff from the scope you need
            $scope.messages = angular.copy($scope.messages);
        };

        init();

        $scope.messages=[];
        //.....
        //Eventually this reaches $scope.messages.push({..});
    }],
    return  {
        restrict: 'EA', 
        scope: {
            live: '&',
            data: '&',
            messages: '&',
        },
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: '/directives/templates/streaming.html'
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't need the parent scope for anything, I want to use my own scope, with my own variables, which will then be reflected on the directive view, not the parent view